Download files from Firebase storage if they reach a certain size
I can't download files located in a folder in Firebase storage after they reach a certain size, is there any solution to this problem?
async function downloadFilesAsZip(folderPath, zipFilename) {
            console.log('Button clicked');
            document.getElementById('status').innerText = "please wait...";

        const storageRef = storage.ref().child(folderPath);

        try {
            // List all files in the folder
            const fileRefs = await storageRef.listAll();

            // Create a new instance of JSZip
            const zip = new JSZip();

            // Add each file to the zip
            await Promise.all(fileRefs.items.map(async (itemRef) => {
                const downloadURL = await itemRef.getDownloadURL();
                const response = await fetch(downloadURL);
                const fileBlob = await response.blob();
                zip.file(itemRef.name, fileBlob);
            }));

            // Generate the zip file asynchronously
            const zipBlob = await zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" });

            // Create a download link and trigger download
            const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
            downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(zipBlob);
            downloadLink.download = zipFilename;
            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
            downloadLink.click();
            document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);

            document.getElementById('status').innerText = "download should start..";
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching or downloading files:', error);
            document.getElementById('status').innerText = "Error fetching or downloading files. Check console for details.";
        }
    }

I FOUND A SOLUTION: i changed JSZIP call to the latest version and it's was so much fast!

What do you mean by "can't download files"?  Is there an error?  What is it?  Which line of code causes it?  What is the size limit you observe?  What can we do to reproduce the problem on our own?  Please edit the question to include your debugging details.

nothing is catched, the browser just stops responding

What do you mean by "stops responding"?  Please edit the question to share all of your debugging information, including all of your specific observations.

i meant no errors are showing in the browser console, what logs should i post?

Add logging around every single line of code, then share the results of your logging so we can see how this code actually executes.

it's stops in this line const zipBlob = await zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" });

Please edit your post to share your debugging details.  If important observations are buried in comments, people might not see them.  Also I'll point out that nothing you've shared so far supports your idea that downloads fails when they reach a certain size.  You should provide those debugging details as well so that we can clearly see what the problem is.

Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.

@DougStevenson i found the solution, thank you
